# Disable Java web service Endpoint Wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I'm developing a webservice and using Enpoint.publish() from the Javax package to publish the service.

Its only a small utility service, but going into production, I don't want to publish the wsdl to remote clients. I've googled around quite a bit - but most results are people having difficulties consuming a web service with no wsdl - not actually how to disable it on the service.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Also just to clarify. I'm ok disabling the wsdl altogether. The important point is that its not available for remote clients - even if that means its disabled for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If the clients are coming from outsite the network use firewall rules to prevent access to the wsdl.